# Output from while loop not working

Tags: java

Apologies for posting about this topic twice today, this one is a different question. So I am working on a java problem at the moment where I am creating a program that simulates the old TV quiz show, You Bet Your Life. The game show host, Groucho Marx, chooses a secret word, then chats with the contestants for a while. If either contestant uses the secret word in a sentence, he or she wins $100.00.

My program is meant to check for this secret word.

Here is my code:

```
        import java.util.Scanner; 

        public class Groucho{
          String secret; 

          Groucho(String secret){
            this.secret = secret; 
          }

          public boolean saysSecret(String line){
            if(secret.equals(line)){
              return(true);
            }
            else{
              return(false);
            }
          }

          public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
            String line = in.nextLine();
            Groucho g = new Groucho(line);

            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
              String guess = in.nextLine();

              /*Not sure about these next two lines:
               *String answer = g.saysSecret(guess);
              */System.out.println(answer);

            }
      }  

}
```

When I run it nothing happens. I thought it should be returning true or false? What I would actually like it to do is if the line contains the secret word, it prints a message that says “You have won $100” and tells what the secret word is. Could anyone point me in the right direction?
Many thanks
Miles

Comment: Check the result of `saysSecret()`

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger?

Comment: you code won't compile because the line that declares `answer` is commented out.  When you post code on your questions, please post the specific version of the code that illustrates the problem that you describe.  Not code that has been changed since you've last encountered the problem

Comment: You can't just assign a boolean to a String.

Answer (score 1):

As Sotirios points out, you should use saysSecret(String) to check if the guess is correct.
So the loop could look like:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String guess = in.nextLine();
    if (g.saysSecret(guess))
    {
        System.out.println("You got it! The word was: "+g.secret);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Aw, try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense to me! One extra thing, when I run the program it will return either 'true' or 'false' (along with the output messages created) e.g. "You have won $100! The secret word is hello" and then on the line below it will say 'true'.

Anyway to remove the 'true' or 'false'? 
thanks!

Comment: Hm, can you update your main post to contain your current code? And make sure that you have no other System.out.println() calls anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you are assigning a boolean value to a String. You should compare the return value of g.saysSecret(guess), and then if this value is true print your successful message (or even print a failure message if this value is false).

Also, you have said:

> What I would actually like it to do is if the line contains the secret word ...

so

```
secret.equals(line)
```

is not what you want since that will be true only if the entire line is equal to the secret word. For search for a word inside a line you could use:

```
line.contains(secret)
```

or maybe you need a more elaborated method for case insensitive matchs and so on.